# Remove duplicates from array in Ruby and perform an operation on a specific index

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to remove duplicates from an array in Ruby and perform an operation on a specific index while removing duplicates. Let me explain with an example:

```rb
arr = [["A", "Red", 7], ["A", "Red", 8], ["B", "Red", 3],["B", "Blue", 2],
       ["B", "Blue", 3], ["C", "Blue", 3], ["C", "Black", 1], ["D", nil, 4],
       ["D", nil, 5]]
```

I need to check if first and second indexes are the same, and if they are same, take a sum of third indexes while removing the duplicates.

So I need the output as:

```rb
[["A", "Red", 15],  ["B", "Red", 3],["B", "Blue", 5], ["C", "Blue", 3],
 ["C", "Black", 1], ["D", nil, 9]]
```

Comment: This was my first post on SO and i am surprised how fast, elegant and correct answers returned. All 3 answers worked fine for me. Thank you all for this, and special thanks to Cary for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(*a,n),h| h[a] += n }.map(&:flatten)
  #=> [["A", "Red", 15], ["B", "Red", 3], ["B", "Blue", 5], ["C", "Blue", 3],
  #    ["C", "Black", 1], ["D", nil, 9]]
```

The first step of the calculation is:

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(*a,n),h| h[a] += n }
  #=> {["A", "Red"]=>15, ["B", "Red"]=>3, ["B", "Blue"]=>5,
  #    ["C", "Blue"]=>3, ["C", "Black"]=>1, ["D", nil]=>9}
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the default value. All that means is that when Ruby's parser expands `h[a] += 1` to

```
h[a] = h[a] + n
```

`h[a]` on the right returns `h`'s default value, `0`, if `h` does not have a key `a`. For example, when `h` is empty,

```
h[["A", "Red"]] = h[["A", "Red"]] + 7 #=> 0 + 7 =>  7
h[["A", "Red"]] = h[["A", "Red"]] + 8 #=> 7 + 8 => 15
```

`h` does not have a key `["A", "Red"]` in the first expression, so  `h[["A", "Red"]]` on the right returns the default value, `0`, whereas `h` does have that key in the second expression so the default value does not apply.

`h.map(&:flatten)` is shorthand for

```
h.map { |a| a.flatten }
```

When the block variable `a` is set equal to first key-value pair of `h`,

```
a #=> [["A", "Red"], 15]
```

So

```
a.flatten
  #=> ["A", "Red", 15]
```

To understand`|(*a,n),h|` we need to construct the enumerator

```
enum = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["A", "Red", 7], ["A", "Red", 8], ["B", "Red", 3],
  #     ["B", "Blue", 2], ["B", "Blue", 3], ["C", "Blue", 3],
  #     ["C", "Black", 1], ["D", nil, 4], ["D", nil, 5]]
  #     :each_with_object({})>
```

We now generate the first value from the enumerator (using [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)) and assign values to the block variables:

```
(*a,n),h = enum.next
  #=> [["A", "Red", 7], {}] 
a #=> ["A", "Red"] 
n # => 7 
h #=> {}
```

The way in which the array returned by `enum.next` is broken up into constituent elements that are assigned to the block variables is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). It is a powerful and highly useful techique.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and helping me understanding the logic behind array decomposition Cary. I tried your code with longer arrays like [["A", "Red", "Ruby", 8, 7]] and it worked fine too. So, what **"*a"** means here is, take all the elements of an array up to its last element, am i right?

Comment: Tuna-man, if `*a, n = [1,2,3,4]` then `n` is assigned the last value, `4` and `a` is assigned an array of everything before, `[1,2,3]`. Try `n, *a = [1,2,3,4]`, `a, n = [1,2,3,4]` and `*a, n = [1,2]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method in combination with [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) to do this.

```
arr = [["A", "Red", 7], ["A", "Red", 8], ["B", "Red", 3],["B", "Blue", 2], ["B", "Blue", 3], ["C", "Blue", 3], ["C", "Black", 1], ["D", nil, 4], ["D", nil, 5]]

result = arr.group_by { |*keys, _number| keys }
            .map { |keys, items| keys << items.sum(&:last) }
#=> [["A", "Red", 15], ["B", "Red", 3], ["B", "Blue", 5], ["C", "Blue", 3], ["C", "Black", 1], ["D", nil, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) and push the first 2 elements as key to the hash object:

```
new_arr = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0 }) do |val, hash|
  hash[val[0..1]] += val[-1]
end.map(&:flatten)

new_arr #=> [["A", "Red", 15],
         #=> ["B", "Red", 3],
         #=> ["B", "Blue", 5],
         #=> ["C", "Blue", 3],
         #=> ["C", "Black", 1],
         #=> ["D", nil, 9]]
```

or just the `each` with a `Hash` object defined with a default proc: `Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0 }`

This will, of course, do not work if your values in subarrays differ, for example `["A", "Red", 5]` and `["A", "red", 7]` will be treated differently.